# Reduce the number of conditional operators (4) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3) in SONAR

Tags: java, sonarlint

From below piece of code sonar showing Major issue like **Reduce the number of conditional operators (4) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3)** but those all condition mandatory to keep in this block

With what changes sonar will be happy from below code

### Code

```
    if (cartResJsonObj.getString(AccessIdConstants.APP_STATUS_MSG).equalsIgnoreCase("INVALID_REQUEST")
                                || cartResJsonObj.getString(AccessIdConstants.APP_STATUS_MSG).equalsIgnoreCase("ERR_EMPTY")
                                || cartResJsonObj.getString(AccessIdConstants.APP_STATUS_MSG).equalsIgnoreCase("ERR_INVALID_DATA")
                                || cartResJsonObj.getString(AccessIdConstants.APP_STATUS_MSG).equalsIgnoreCase("ERR_SIM_DATE_MISSING")
                                || cartResJsonObj.getString(AccessIdConstants.APP_STATUS_MSG).equalsIgnoreCase("ERR_SIM_NOT_YET_ELIGIBLE")) {
    errorMessage = ErrorMessages.EPO_VALIDATEOTP_ERR_04;
    detailsMessage = ErrorConstants.INVALID_REQUEST;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the string, uppercased, against some collection, e.g.

```
Arrays.asList("INVALID_REQUEST", "ERR_EMPTY")
    .contains(cartResJsonObj.getString(AccessIdConstants.APP_STATUS_MSG).toUpperCase())
```

(The collection can be stored in a static final variable, rather than building each time)

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate all error codes into a dedicated `enum`. This would also help to reduce the usage of *magic strings* (analog to *magic numbers*), since the enum can safely be used elsewhere instead of copying the strings.

```
private enum ErrorStatus {

    INVALID_REQUEST,
    ERR_EMPTY,
    ERR_INVALID_DATA,
    ERR_SIM_DATE_MISSING,
    ERR_SIM_NOT_YET_ELIGIBLE;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final Map<String, ErrorStatus> ERROR_CODES;

    static {
        Map<String, ErrorStatus> codes = new HashMap<>();
        for (ErrorStatus value : values()) {
            codes.put(value.toString(), value);
        }
        ERROR_CODES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(codes);
    }

    public static ErrorStatus from(String value) {
        return ERROR_CODES.get(value.toUpperCase());
    }

    public static boolean matches(String value) {
        return from(value) != null;
    }

}
```

Your original call can then be simplified to:

```
// no need to call #getString multiple times like in your example
String status = cartResJsonObj.getString(AccessIdConstants.APP_STATUS_MSG);

if (ErrorStatus.matches(status)) {
    errorMessage = ErrorMessages.EPO_VALIDATEOTP_ERR_04;
    detailsMessage = ErrorConstants.INVALID_REQUEST;
}
```

Comment: Also an advantage: You can include other status in this enum and introduce a boolean flag to indicate if a status is an error.